# jquery associative array made up of variables

Tags: jquery, associative-array

I have the following code:

```
var paramTemp = ret.split('^');
    $.each(paramTemp, function(key, elem) {
      var splitTemp = elem.split('*');
      params = {
    splitTemp[0]: splitTemp[1]
      };
    });
```

I get complaints when I try to set the key to splitTemp[0]. How do I set a key to a variables value?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI - Javascript doesn't have associative arrays.  Associative arrays are actually objects, but due to the way Javascript allows alternate syntax (such as in Nick Craver's post), you can use array syntax to reference object variables.

This has no affect on how to fix your problem, but I just thought I'd share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), it should look like this:

```
var paramTemp = ret.split('^'), params = {};
$.each(paramTemp, function(key, elem) {
  var splitTemp = elem.split('*');
  params[splitTemp[0]] = splitTemp[1];
});
```

In JavaScript these have the same effect:

```
obj.name = value;
obj["name"] = value;
```